# Move Parts of a circle out at equal distance

Tags: adobe-illustrator

I'm trying to create something like this using Illustrator CC 2015.  I know that I can just create an circle and use the scissor tool to break the circle apart.

I'm just wondering how I can move all the parts away from each other equally to create that gap.

Any ideas?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To create a diagram like this, you can make use of Dashed Strokes in the Stroke panel. However, if your diagram needs dashes of different lengths, this method can only adjust up to 3 segment sizes.

**Step 1:** Draw an ellipse with the Circle tool and add a stroke.

**Step 2:** Using the **Dashed Stroke feature**, start by setting the gap size you desire. *Note: This gap size will remain consistent regardless of circle size provided your scale strokes settings haven't been changed from default.*

**Step 3:** You can now use the first dash size box to adjust the size of the dashes. This will decide how many segments you want in your diagram.

**Note:** If you resize your circle after setting the gap size, **you can readjust your segments with the dash size box until your segments are divided consistently.**

[image]

Comment: The only problem with this is you can only set 3 dash lengths in the stroke panel and the example image has different sized segments

Comment: Ah, well spotted @Cai, didn't think of that!

Comment: @Cai Oh yea, thanks for noticing.  Just needed equal parts this time around.  I'll remember this for next time.

Answer (score 3):

The easiest way would be to separate your circle segments with stroked paths originating from the center of your circle.

You can then outline your strokes (**Object → Path → Outline Stroke**) and use the Pathfinder panel to cut out the segments from your circle.

[image]

Comment: thanks for the answer.  I think adding a dashed stroke is the easiest option here.  Appreciate it.

Comment: The only problem with a dashed stroke is that you can only set 3 dash sizes in the stroke panel (and your example image has different sized segments), if that isn't a problem then it is definitely easier to use a dashed stroke yes.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using the Scissor tool, you can just create a circle then add dashed Stroke to it and adjust the gap.